# Mustache php gettext()

Tags: php, templates, web-applications, kohana, mustache

I am experimenting with kostache, "mustache for kohana framework".

Is there any way I can use simple PHP functions in mustache template files.
I know logic and therefore methods are against logic-less design principle, but I'm talking about very simple functionality.

For example:

- `gettext('some text')` or `__('some text')`
- get the base url; in kohana -> `Url::site('controller/action')`

Comment: Mustache. Huh. Is there a Tom Selleck option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bobthecow is working on an experimental feature that will allow you to call a function as a callback.

Check out the [higher-order-sections](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/tree/feature/higher-order-sections) branch of the repository and [the ticket](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php/issues/4) to go with it.

Comment: I tried that already, and whatever I do it doesn't work. I'm on PHP5.2, so no anonymous functions. I have this function in the view class: public function i18n(){return array('I18n', 'get');}... and in the template {{#i18n}}Hello{{/i18n}}... it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Nevermind, it works now. I copied the wrong branch from github. Thanks!

Comment: But how do you extract messages from the templates? xgettext doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "ICanHaz" http://icanhazjs.com/

and then you can declare your mustache templates as

```
<script id="welcome" type="text/html">
<p>Welcome, {{<?php echo __('some text') ?>}}! </p>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do this now with Bobthecow's implementation of Mustache Engine. We need **anonymous functions** here, which are passed to the Template Object along with other data.

Have a look at the following example:

```
<?php
$mustache = new Mustache_Engine;
# setting data for our template
$template_data = [
    'fullname' => 'HULK',
    'bold_it' => function($text){
        return "<b>{$text}</b>";
    }
];
# preparing and outputting
echo $mustache->render("{{#bold_it}}{{fullname}}{{/bold_it}} !", $template_data);
```

In the above example, '**bold_it**' points to our function which is pasalong withwith other data to our template. The value of '**fullname**' is being passed as a *parameter* to this function.

Please note that passing parameters is not mandatory in Mustache. You can even call the php function wothout any parameters, as follows:

```
<?php
# setting data for our template
$template_data = [
    'my_name' => function(){
        return 'Joe';
    }
];
# preparing and outputting
echo $mustache->render("{{my_name}} is a great guy!", $template_data); # outputs: Joe is a great guy!
```

Credits: http://dwellupper.io/post/24/calling-php-functions-for-data-in-mustache-php